# React Native DrawerLayoutAndroid + Toolbar

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, toolbar, drawerlayout

I've tried so many examples, and I couldn't do Toolbar work with a DrawerLayout.

Can anywone fix the example above, and show me in rnplay how does it work?

This is an example of what I tried to do.

https://rnplay.org/apps/telLVQ

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a height to your . Also set styles to your view to fill the screen.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7915

Comment: Thanks holoto! Finally after 3 days, did it work! =)
Its strange because they work ok, without the Height when they are not togheter!
Thank you!